# Searching each item on a list and returning all Matches

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, lookup

I have the following Example Raw Data set containing a list of chemicals and the suppliers providing these. This exists on another sheet and I users to be able to pull through the information via a search as shown below.

[image]

I appreciate that I can use FILTER to return multiple results in a dynamic array however this doesnt work to search for multiple chemicals.

Essentially I just wish to allow a user to create a list of values and from the raw data matching results for suppliers and the original raw material searches for are pulled through for each.

I'm not sure if this is achievable using just formulas or if this will require vba but if anyone could comment that would be great. Using VBA I suppose I could loop through the search list for each and populate the next cell down depending on whether the current cell is blank or not. Ideally however I would like to have the data populate as the list is entered and not have to click a button for a macro to run.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: In desired result area how `E=5`, `D=6`?

Comment: I cannot understand how your 'desired result has been made'... 1 for A is the first occurrence, B is missing, C is the first occurrence, where from is taken 5 for E and 6 for D? How E reaches the result column? What the values without labels in H:H column do mean?

Comment: Please see updated image to understand where the data comes from.

Comment: For example using FILTER E returns 3 results. Hence why the data is not one to one on the right.

Comment: @Harun24HR yeah it doesnt in reality because the data is not one to one. i.e. E doesnt correlate to 5 and 6 does not link to 6. The rows of the 2 columns on the right are independent. Hopefully you can see that in the raw data some letters return multiple values and so as soon as that happens the data can no longer work one to one. Essentially I just want to known if I can return a results list, containing every match for letters A,C, E and D. DOes that make sense? Apologies I wasnt clearer before.

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi so the raw data on the left is what I wish to search by letter on the right.  B is not included just because I am randomly searching a list of letters. In this case the letters are A,C,E and D. So A = 1, C = 12,5,6, E = 10,9,10 and D = 7. Does that make sense? The rows in columns H and I do not share a one to one relationship but rather the results list is populated by finding all of the results for A (1) then C, (15,5,6) and so on. If the list were to search for A,C, B the results would be 1, 15,5,6,  8,3. Hope that clears things up.

Comment: @Harun24HR * D does not link to 6.

Comment: I can only state that this way of "processing" looks, at least, strange... You did not say (in your question) anything about 'searching' by only some strings of column B:B. But, even so, how do you use that enumeration without knowing each number are coming from which searched string? Are you sure that this is what you really need?

Comment: Do you need both columns from your H:H column, or you only use them as search criteria and need only the values from I:I, no matter to which search string they belong?

Comment: @FaneDuru I appreciate that I may need to include an adjacent column which also returns the corresponding letter e.g. 12,5,6 I would get C,C,C. There are a number of tutorials out there performing single searches to return multiple results. However there isnt much on how to search for multiple items with multiple results. It seems reasonable to want to know this? I'm dealing with Raw materials for multiple suppliers. Instead of searching for each raw material individually I would like to generate a list of which suppliers supply each raw material for all of my raw materials.

Comment: Then, edit your question and show as what you really need (admit). Otherwise, where to place/return that new admitted request? Should the J:J column to be used, as you tried justifying each value origin? Change them, meaning that the search string to be in column I:I and the values in J:J?

Comment: I don't have access to Excel365, but `=FILTER(B4:C23,MATCH(B4:B23,H4:H7,0))` works fine in Sheets. If it doesn't in Excel, I'd try `=FILTER(B4:C23,COUNTIF(H4:H7,B4:B23))`

Comment: @FaneDuru I have updated the question. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @BrakNicku Works perfect, thank you!

Comment: It is clear now. If still interested, please test the code I posted.

Comment: @BrakNicku May be very simple, but if you’d like to post as an answer I’d be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next code. It takes the list from range "H4" to the last row on H:H and placed the processed result in columns I:J, starting from the fourth row:

```
Sub ListOccurrences()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrList, dict As Object
   Dim arrIt, arrFin, mtch, i As Long, El, k As Long
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet  'use here the sheet you need
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on the B:B column
   arrList = sh.Range("H4:H" & sh.Range("H" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row).value 'the 2D array list
   arrList = Application.Transpose(arrList)            'the 1D array list
   arr = sh.Range("B4:C" & lastR).value              'put the range to be processed in an array
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")  'create a Scripting dictionary to keep the values per key
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)                             'iterate between array rows
        mtch = Application.match(arr(i, 1), arrList, 0) 'check if the search strinig exists in the list array
        If Not IsError(mtch) Then                          'if it exist in the list:
            If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then              'if a dictionary key not exist:
                dict.Add arr(i, 1), arr(i, 2)                   'create the key with its value
            Else
                dict(arr(i, 1)) = dict(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) 'add to the existing key a new value, separated by "|"
            End If
        End If
   Next i
   'process the dictionary items:
   ReDim arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To UBound(arr)) 'redim the final array at the level of the range to be process number of rows
   For Each El In dict.Keys                       'iterate betwen the dictionary keys
        arrIt = Split(dict(El), "|")                 'split each key value by "|"
        If IsArray(arrIt) Then                     'if there are more than a value:
            For i = 0 To UBound(arrIt)
                k = k + 1
                arrFin(2, k) = El: arrFin(1, k) = arrIt(i) 'place the key and the value in the final array
            Next i
        Else
            k = k + 1
            arrFin(2, k) = El: arrFin(1, k) = arrIt       'place the key and all its values in the final array
        End If
    Next
    If k > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To k)        'keep in the final array only the filled array elements (not empty)
        arrFin = Application.Transpose(arrFin)        'transpose the array to return exactly what needed
    End If
    sh.Range("I4").Resize(k, 2).value = arrFin       'drop the result at once
End Sub
```

I commented all code lines which may not be clear enough about they do.

Please, send some feedback and confirm that you understand the code logic...

Comment: Hi there, I really appreciate the effort so thank you.

Comment: @Nick Welcome! But, does it return what you need? I couldn't do anything until I understood what you need...

Comment: Code works great. For tidyness I think I will stick to the formula above but Its always useful to learn more vba

Comment: @Nick Not any problem for me! I like helping and experimenting pieces of code when I am able to understand what is to be done...

Comment: Apologies if I wasnt clear enough before. Im sure ill be returning to VBA problems shortly so perhaps you can help me with them ;) haha thanks!

Comment: @Nick Learning of asking a question makes part of the game. You cannot program anything if you are not able to explain what is to be done, in a clear way. Like I said, I do not have any problem. I only tried to make you clarify the issue. I have some doubts that somebody else could suggest a solution without our clarification comments...